# Why this plugin is not working?

Tags: php, plugin-development, jquery, javascript

I am testing jQuery in my wordpress plugin. Two files 1. main_plugin.php 2. js_plugin.js (Both in the same directory HelloWorld).
CODE:
PHP FILE:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: jQuery Test Plugin
Plugin URI: http://www.rabwahnetwork.net
Description: This plugin is a test
Author: Rana Faiz Ahmed
Author URI: http://www.rabwahnetwork.net
*/

function load_my_script()
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', WP_PLUGIN_URL . 'HelloWorld/js_plugin.js', array("jquery"), false, true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_script' );
```

JS file:

```
jQuery('.entry-header').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WP_PLUGIN_URL` doesn't have a trailing slash, so your script tag is likely trying to load a file from the wrong location.

That said, **don't use `WP_PLUGIN_URL`**, use [`plugins_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) instead.

```
plugins_url( '/HelloWorld/js_plugin.js' )
```

Comment: Nope, no effect!

Comment: is your file being loaded?

Comment: Yeah I'm editing it from the wordpress backend. Absolutely it is being loading else I wouldn't be editing it.

Comment: whether or not you can edit a file on the back end has nothing to do with whether or not it's successfully loading on the front end, your assumption is incorrect.

Comment: So, how would I know?

Comment: your browser's error console

Comment: Should it be at the bottom of the page? Before `</body>` ???

Comment: it will be output wherever your theme calls [`wp_footer()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer).

Comment: No, its not loading...

Comment: But why ???????

Comment: Helloooo ? ? ? ?

Comment: update your question with your current code. make sure all paths are correct and that your plugin is activated and your theme calls `wp_footer()`

Comment: oops it wasn't activated. HAHAHAHHAHAHAHAHAHAHHA

Comment: Sorry about wasting your time really am!